# I want to make sign in & up for my site with Django but it doesn't work

Tags: python, html, django, web

## form.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):                               
   name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=True) 
   password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)


class SignInForm(forms.Form):                                                             
   email = forms.EmailField()                              
   password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, min_length=8)
```

## view.py

```
def Sign_Up(request.POST):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        name = cd['name']
        email = cd['email']
        password = cd['password']
        us = User..objects.get(email__exact=email, password__exact=password)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'User Login Page.html', {'form':form})


def Sign_In(request.POST):
if request.method =='POST' :
    form = SignInForm(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        F = form.cleaned_data
        Eemail = F['email']
        Epassword = F['password']
        try:
            user = User.objects.filter(email=Eemail)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            form = SignInForm()
            return render(request, "Admin Login Page.html", {'form': form})
        if User.password == Epassword:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
form = SignInForm()
return render(request,"Admin Login Page.html",{'form':form})
```

I want to make a sign in & up for my site with *Django* but it doesn't work!
When I *click on the submit button* my sign up directly goes to the `HttpRsponseDirect` address even with empty parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Sign_Up(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            name = cd['name']
            email = cd['email']
            password = cd['password']
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db() 
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request,'signup.html', {'form':form})

def Sign_In(request):
    if request.method =='POST' :
        form = SignInForm(request)
        if form.is_valid():
            F = form.cleaned_data
            Eemail = F['email']
            Epassword = F['password']
            user=authenticate(username=F,password=Epassword)
            if  user is not None:
                 return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
            else:
                form=SignInForm()
                message='login failed'
            retuen render(request,'login.html',{'form':form,'message':message})
```

look at upside code

Comment: Please explain what you have modified to the code to make it work.

Comment: first in sign up why you get all user object? 'us = User.objects.all()'  you should create a User object and user need username email and password there was very different way to save user and in sign in you need 'authenticate()' for login user

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have multiple security experts on the job; please, please, please let someone else handle your logins like Google or Facebook. like when you go to create account it says "use google to sign in"